# Remove ALL named ranges including invalid references?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried every script I can find to remove invalid reference named ranges without any luck.  I even tried removing *all* named ranges using the script below, yet the invalid references remain.  Does such solution exist via script, or do I have to manually delete a 100 or so named ranges manually?

```javascript
var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges();
for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
  namedRanges[i].remove();
}
```

[Developer Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#remove())

Answer (score 2):

### Updated Answer:

**There seems to be a bug:**

A user reported the following issue:

[Spreadsheet getNamedRanges() does not return named ranges show as #REF in Spreadsheet UI](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126262167)

you can star the issue (top left corner) to increase visibility but I think the issue is not popular enough. I would advice use to migrate the data into a different sheet as a workaround so you won't have to delete the named ranges manually.

You can also prove the bug if you call `console.log(namedRanges)`, you will get an empty array `[]` but clearly your spreadsheet has many named ranges.

---

---

Your solution worked for me and deleted all the named ranges in an example file I created.

However, I found some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673407/removing-invalid-named-ranges-in-gas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824122/how-to-delete-all-namedranges-in-google-spreadsheet) which recommend the spreadsheet method [removeNamedRange(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#removeNamedRange(String)) instead.

Try the following code:

```
 function myFunction() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
    const namesR = namedRanges.map(nr=>nr.getName());   
    namesR.forEach(name=>{
       ss.removeNamedRange(name);
    });
}
```

Comment: If this does not work, please provide exact details on how you execute this function. It might be related to that. If it is also not that, then it is probably a bug which you can report in the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think the difference must be that my ranges are from copied sheets from another file.  I’m just going to approach my entire process.

Comment: @TC76 from where are you running the script? are you sure the script is bounded to the same spreadsheet you want to delete the namedRanges? Because `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` gets the **current** spreadsheet which is bound the to script. Namely, if you click on Tools=> Script editor in a particular spreadsheet, then that script is bound to this spreadsheet. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I believe so. I’m not savvy enough to answer confidently, but yes, if I open the script editor, that is where the script is.

Comment: yes, but you open the script editor in the very same spreadsheet that you want to delete the namedRanges from. Is that correct? Please share a copy of your sheet for trouble shooting, remove all the personal data from it. This will help me find the problem easier :) @TC76

Comment: Thanks for offering to look. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_ka0zx_ngyplajI1O4sdvdBWGjKnE8EmYT86hd4M_Q/edit#gid=1478720422

Comment: @TC76 Unfortunately, I can't do anything with that file. I can't see the script, I can't see the named ranges, I can't delete anything if I want to. It would be nice if you let the users create a copy of that file so I can play around.

Comment: Sorry.  Unintentional mistake.  Fixed

Comment: @TC76 unfortunately, there seems to be a bug with undefined namedRanges.. I updated my answer and gave some suggestions regarding workarounds.